# How to add NSMutableDictionary to Array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

Firstly I am accessing an API service with help of `Alamofire`. After success I display they array in an `tableView`. Now I want to add `NSMutableDictionary` to that response array for `selectedIndexPath` only.

Comment: Don't use `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift 3+. Use `Swift Dictionary`. Also, any code might be helpful, because if you don't share, I'd say it's in line 33 of the third file.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide more information. What have you tried already, did you get an error? See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You cannot add a dictionary to an array, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @koen, why not? `var arr: [Any] = [[String: String]()]`

Comment: I stand corrected. But is that what @chaitanya_ios is trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

```
yourArrar[selectedIndex] = yourDictionary
```

This will replace the array selected index dictionary with yours